# Is it possible to make a jQuery click event triggering a function that plays a sound overlap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I am trying to make a very simple drum sampler using simple javascript and jQuery. I have jQuery click events, along with keyboard input events triggering a function that plays the desired sound. But the function will not trigger again while the sound is still playing.

Example: The Hi-Hat sound will only play again after the entire wav file is played.

I need the sounds to be able to overlap over themselves to create a beat. Is this possible with jQuery?

Code Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var hh = document.createElement('audio');
    hh.setAttribute('src', 'assets/sounds/hh.wav');


    function rubyTrigger() {
        hh.play();
        $("#ruby-cover").animate({opacity: "0.5"}, 50);
        $("#ruby-cover").animate({opacity: "1"}, 75);
    }


    $("#ruby").click(function() {
        rubyTrigger();
    });


    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 106) {
            rubyTrigger();
        } 
    });

}
```

Comment: What about creating multiple `audio` elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `document.createElement('audio')`in to your `rubyTrigger` function.

```js
function rubyTrigger() {
  var hh = document.createElement('audio');
  hh.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.soundjig.com/mp3/soundfx/drumkits/CY0010.mp3');

  hh.play();
}


$("#ruby").click(function() {
  rubyTrigger();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="ruby">
  CLICK
</button>
```

This will create a new audio element every time you click the button without effecting any that are still playing.

I'm not sure but I assume that these elements will be garbage collected when the audio finishes playing.